# How to read a file into a hashmap or dictionary in c#

Tags: c#

I have a file with values like this

```
keyA: Value1
keyB: Value2
keyC: Value3
```

Is there a easy way to consume this file in c# so that I have it in a hashmap or something similar?

Comment: What have tried so far? Looks like it would fit nicely into a Dictionary.

Comment: Yes. Have you tried anything yet? Look into `IDictionary`.

Comment: [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) fits your needs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `File.ReadLines` method to read the lines,split the lines with `Split` method and put them into dictionary using `ToDictionary`:

```
var dict = File.ReadLines("path") 
           .ToDictionary(x => x.Split(':')[0], x => x.Split(':')[1]);
```

Comment: Might be my OCD, but `.Select(x => x.Split(':')).ToDictionary(...)` would be faster, without complicating the code much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    public IDictionary<string, string> ReadFromFile(string fileName)
    {
        var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        using (var file = new StreamReader(fileName))
        {

            string line;
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                var values = line.Split(':');
                if (values.Length == 2)
                {
                    result[values[0].Trim()] = values[1].Trim();
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```